# Copy and compare specific cells to one sheet, in VBA Excel (Watch out mindbreaker!!)

Tags: excel, vba

i have a quite specific question about programming in excel. I'm moderately skilled in VBA but can't get my head around this one.

I have multiple sheets containing an list of id's and values. From these multiple sheets i want to make one complete sheet with values.

Example:

Sheet wk1

```
ID  - Var  - Var1  - Var 2

10 - A - B - C

14 - aa - bb- cc
```

Sheet wk2

```
ID  - Var  - Var1  - Var 2

11 - d - e - f

14 - AA - BB- CC
```

the function must make the following list

Sheet combined

ID - wk1(Var - Var 1 - Var 2) - wk2(Var - Var 1 - Var 2)

```
10 - A - B - C - - - 

11 - - - - d - e - f

14 - aa - bb - cc - AA - BB - CC
```

I hope this makes it clear...

I think at first the function must define if every ID is present. And per iterated sheet copy values in the corresponding columns.

Currently i have the following code for it to work. I must say it is under progress, but i need some pointers:

```
Sub getalldata()

Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim rnum As Long
Dim ShName As Variant, BaseWks As Variant
Dim rangearray As Variant

' Get all data from the eight excel files in the designated directory
' Compare Projnrs, an then paste values according in the designated slots
'
' Path\folder location of the files.
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Source/"

' External sheet name. To get data from
ShName = "Report"
' Range of columns to paste corresponding data too. sorted in per week eg {Wk1Val1, Wk1Val2 , Wk1Val3; Wk2Val1, Wk2Val2 , Wk2Val3 etc.
rangearray = [{"D2","E2","F2";"G2","H2","I2";"J2","K2","L2";"M2","N2","O2";"P2","Q2","R2";"S2","T2","U2";"V2","W2","X2";"Y2","Z2","AA2"}]
' Internal sheet name. To paste data too
ShName = "Report"


' Add a slash after MyPath if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files in the
' folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Change application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

rnum = 1

'Sort array of max 8 excel files to get wk 1 results before wk2 reuslts
BubbleSort MyFiles

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = 0 To 7
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            On Error Resume Next
            ' Set the filter range.
            ' Compare content and fill additional


                For Each c In mybook.Worksheets("Report").Range(Cells(39, 3), Cells(65536, 3).End(xlUp)).Cells
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, Worksheets("Inputinfo").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                    ' String is in range, calculate values and paste accordingly

                    'Paste val1 ( Total profit (AQ+BA))
                    Worksheets("Inputinfo").Cells(c, 4 + FNum).Value = c.Offset(, 40).Value + c.Offset(, 50).Value
                    'Paste val2 (Not  yet allocated (K+BA-(R+AV))-(AQ+BA))
                    Worksheets("Inputinfo").Cells(c, 5 + FNum).Value = (c.Offset(, 8).Value + c.Offset(, 50).Value - (c.Offset(, 15).Value + c.Offset(, 45).Value)) - (c.Offset(, 40).Value + c.Offset(, 50).Value)
                    'Paste val3 (Net proj contri colum AT)
                    Worksheets("Inputinfo").Cells(c, 6 + FNum).Value = c.Offset(, 43).Value
                Else
                    'String is not in range, take last used row to paste projnr and values in columns

                End If

                Next

            ' Close the workbook without saving.
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

        ' Open the next workbook.
    Next FNum

End If

' Restore the application properties.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Mathijs

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mergeRecords()

Dim rng1, rng2, c As Range
Dim r As Long

r = 1
```

'EDIT

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("A").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("A").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
Set rng2 = Sheets("B").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("B").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In rng1
    Set c = rng2.Find(cell.Text)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("C").Range("A" & r).Value = cell.Text & "-" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & _
                "-" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Text & "-" & cell.Offset(3, 0).Text & "- - - -"
            r = r + 1
        Else
            Sheets("C").Range("A" & r).Value = cell.Text & "-" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & _
                "-" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Text & "-" & cell.Offset(3, 0).Text & "-" & _
                c.Offset(0, 1).Text & "-" & c.Offset(0, 2).Text & "-" & c.Offset(3, 0).Text
            r = r + 1
        End If
Next cell

For Each cell In rng2
    Set c = rng1.Find(cell.Text)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("C").Range("A" & r).Value = cell.Text & "-" & cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & _
                "-" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Text & "-" & cell.Offset(3, 0).Text & "- - - -"
            r = r + 1
        End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

maybe something like this would work out for you

Comment: This code fails, specifically this fails right away `Sheets("A").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: do you have a sheet called "A"?

Comment: that was a placeholder for whatever your sheets are called

Comment: i think you meant to say `Set rng1 = Sheets("A").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("A").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: absolutely what i meant, or Sheets("A").Range("A65536").End(xlup).row...and the second should be for sheet "B"